# How to compare values of two List Arrays in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, equals

I have two lists as shown:

```
//list one = {1,2,3,4}
listone.add(1);
listone.add(2);
listone.add(3);
listone.add(4);

// list two = {3.0,4}
listtwo.add(3.0);
listtwo.add(4);
```

I tried comparing `3` in `listone` to `3.0` in `listtwo`, but no matter what I do they don't seem to be equal. I was wondering, how can I detect that they are equal?

Also if I try to see they are a subset of each other:

```
Collections.indexOfSubList(listone,listtwo);
```

Apparently this doesn't detect `3.0` as equal to `3`.

So my question is, how do I test that `3` is equal to `3.0`?

Comment: those are just random numbers from user inputs from Scanner

Comment: What's the type of your `List`s, is it `List<int>`?

Comment: You cannot compare incompatible types (types that cannot be auto-boxing or other types). For this reason, one option for your problem is to cast always before adding the item to the list, according to the type you want (seems to be Integer).

Comment: do you mean 3 and 3.0 are equals??

Comment: @Tom I understand, so I either cast them to double or Integer before comparing by itself or adding them to list. Thank you I will test this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the `==` to compare the List contents. Use `compareTo(obj)` instead.

Example:

A) Create two lists

```
ArrayList<Double> myList = new ArrayList<Double>();
//... fill list
ArrayList<Integer> myList2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//....fill list
```

B) Sort them in the same order

C) Loop around and check each element using `.compareTo()`

```
for(int i=0; i<myList.size(); i++){

            if(myList.get(i).compareTo(Double.valueOf(myList2.get(i)))==0){
                //numbers are equal
            }
        }
```

**Of course this solution requires the two list to be same size.**
The `myList.get(i) == (Double)myList2.get(i`) will not work

Answer (score 0):

Convert untyped lists to double lists:

```
    Stream<Double> s1 = listone.stream().map(o->((Number)o).doubleValue());
    List<Double> dblListone = s1.collect(Collectors.toList());

    Stream<Double> s2 = listtwo.stream().map(o->((Number)o).doubleValue());
    List<Double> dblListtwo = s2.collect(Collectors.toList());
```